# Can't pass an object into an angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm defining a variable (highlighter) in my JS file and would like to use it inside an angular controller (that I define in the same JS file). the controller doesn't recognize it.

I tried several ways but they all failed and I'm a bit confused now.
I pasting only the relevant part and general structure of the code.

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var highlighter;  
  window.highlighter = highlighter;
})();

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
 .controller('Controller', function($scope, $window, $http) {

 $scope.highlighter1 = function(side, string, load) {
              highlighter.deserialize(string);         
 };
 })
 })(window.angular);
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens, precisely? How could you call a method deserialize() on highlighter, which is never initialized anywhere? And why do you use global variables?

Comment: Hi. In controllers we can call $window global object. Like $window.highlighter

Comment: Why are you assigning it as `window.highlighter` ? If you want to attach it to window object, then it should be available inside the angular controller as `window` object scope is global.

Answer (score 1):

You are restricting the scope of `highlighter` to the anonymous function you've written in with IIFE. In order to have the scope of it available inside the angular code scope , make it global like this :

```
var highlighter;  
window.highlighter = highlighter;

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
 .controller('Controller', function($scope, $window, $http) {
   $scope.highlighter1 = function(side, string, load) {
        highlighter.deserialize(string);         
   };
 })
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set it in the localstorage and retrive it (it's more persistent) ..:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var highlighter;  
localStorage.setItem('authorizationData', JSON.stringify(highlighter));

 // window.highlighter = highlighter;
})();

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
 .controller('Controller', function($scope, $window, $http,exampleService) {
var fromLocalStorage=exampleService.Get();
 $scope.highlighter1 = function(side, string, load) {
              highlighter.deserialize(string);         
 };
 })
 })(window.angular);

"use strict";

angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory("exampleService", [ "$q", "localStorageService"
function ( $q, localStorageService) {


    // Public Method
    return {
        Set: function (value) {
        localStorageService.remove("authorizationData");
           localStorageService.set("authorizationData",value);
           return localStorageService.get("authorizationData");
        },
        Get: function () {

            return localStorageService.get("authorizationData");
        },

        Remove: function () {
            localStorageService.remove("authorizationData");
        }
    };
}]);
```